# How to enable Emmet in JavaScript in PhpStorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, emmet

In JavaScript, I'm really struggling not being able to use Emmet say in literal templates or suchlike, for example to create a `<div></div>` tag or any code that could be abbreviated for Emmet (e.g. `#div`, `.div`, ...).

I have checked the JSX emmet and I also have tried with `.jsx` file prefixes instead of `.js`, but none have worked so far! I literally searched everywhere for a practical answer but not a single one worked for me!

How can I make it possible?

```js
function myPrint(myVal , color = "secondary") {
    document.write(`
      div
    `)
}
```

There's no way I can make that `div` to get `<div></div>` with Emmet tap key.

Comment: Check this if it works https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html#ws_emmet_enable

Comment: @Bhumit070 One of the first places I looked but was unsuccessful as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EMMET only works in HTML context, you need to tell the IDE that the code in your template literal is HTML. For this, you can either inject HTML language in it temporarily via `Alt+Enter`:

[image]

or use [injection comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.1/using-language-injections.html#use-language-injection-comments):

```
function myPrint(myVal, color = 'secondary') {
  // language=HTML 
  document.write(`
      div
  `)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I recommend that you add this tip to the related web page, as I guess it must be so many people's question : [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html#ws_emmet_enable)